# Back button for social media authentication page?

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework

I need to implement a back button for social media auth pages.
For example - when I tap the FB or Google button I'm redirected to an external credentials and accept screen.
If I want to go back to my app and I'm using android device - it's ok, because I can handle the hardware back button. However - when I'm using a iOs device - it's a bit different as I only have one button.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Frameworks in my app - angularjs and Ionic.

Comment: For the FB SDK, if you use SSO, the FB app (or Safari) will auto-redirect back to your app after the user accepts/cancels the login. There's no need for a back button.

Comment: the cancel or accept buttons are presented after you log in in Facebook. Before that the only option right now is hardware back button.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. There's no way to do this currently. We will consider this use case for the future.